# how to control in client application

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created 2 applications; a Server and Client.
I need to be able to control the client from server

Example:

> If we have music player broadcast
>   video i want when i play video be able
>   to stop ,play, mute the client from
>   server

Please tell me how to start using sockets.

Comment: what do you currently have? do your <s>clinet</s> client and server applications *currently* talk to eachother?

Comment: yes Both connected with each other

Comment: so... what is the difficulty? the comms? or performing the player operations?

Comment: i need help in performing the playing state's controling it

Comment: so... that pretty much doesn't depend *at all* on the sockets or the fact that there is a separate client/server... I really think you should clarify the question a bit...

Answer (score 0):

For Starters..

1. Establish Socket connection from the client to the server.
2. Listen to the keyboard events on
   client ( the machine you are
   controlling from)
3. Using sockets transfer the keyboard
   messages from the client to the
   Server(the machine you would like to
   control)
4. As soon as you receive the message
   on the server use the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   Win32 api to send the keyboard
   messages to the target application
   using the window handle